# Power Savings and Performance Modes on Ubuntu System

Tags: power-management

This might be the only thing I miss from windows.

> There is no way to tell the system to run in high performance mode or in power saver mode.

May be this feature which is already there and I am not sure.

So, Is there a way to change the system operation mode into `high-performance`? Basically, over burning the rams and processors enabling to do several power effective task like *running two OSes on VMWare and not having any performance degradation*.

Or, changing the system's mode into `power-saver` mode affecting the battery life my a lot?

<sub>**P.S:** I dont think what can of hardware I have has to depend *while answering this*. But if is, I will include my system details as well.</sub>

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: Could be a merge candidate -- the proposed duplicate is newer than this one ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could install **Jupiter** (http://www.jupiterapplet.org/)

Which adds this this features to your system and allow you to control it using an indicator

[image]

Just add the PPA ppa:webupd8team/jupiter to your system using this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

Update your reposites and install it using these command(s)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

and you are good to go

Comment: webupd8 says [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html) that this is discontinued, and to use [TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)  instead

Comment: @maxpleaner Note that your install instructions for TLP are outdated, it is now included in the mainline repositories

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/jupiter-0.1.11-1.noarch.rpm/download

Answer (score 8):

Energy save mode in Windows is mostly CPU limiting. You can do that with

```
sudo cpufreq-set -u 0.8Ghz
```

or whatever the desired value is. Check minimum and maximum frequency available with

```
cpufreq-info |grep limits
```

I do that regularly when using a Laptop on battery.

Display brightness adjustments etc. are up to you.

Answer (score 6):

From a Terminal you can do:

```
sudo pm-powersave false
```

to run in high-performance mode.

And to run in powersave mode:

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

Documentation: [PowerManagement/ReducedPower](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower#Using_less_power_with_pm-powersave)

*Full disclosure*: I feel this really should set the CPU governors, but I'm not actually sure it does that!  It might have been a bug on my system that has given me doubt, so it might work just fine for you.  I'd welcome feedback from others on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try slimbook battery. I am using it on one of my laptops,but my opinion is that Ubuntu drains the batteries.
Add the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook
```

And then install:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install slimbookbattery
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is now a feature in Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Comment: powerprofilesctl --help

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel CPU,  (and are using gnome) you can install an extension that does that.https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/power-profiles-daemon

install:

```
sudo apt install power-profiles-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the `linux-tools-common` package, you may then ask for a given CPU frequency governor with one of the following [cpupower](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cpupower.1.html) command (governors names may vary depending on your system):

```shell
# Set governor to powersave
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
# Set governor to performance
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

You may also directly configure CPU frequency settings, e.g. for capping the upper allowed freq.:

```shell
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 2.0GHz
```

Check `cpupower frequency-info` before going on with these commands in order to be able to rollback your settings.

PS: tested OK on Ubuntu 20.04.