# How to put ubuntu in power saver mode

Tags: samba, power-management

I have ubuntu desktop 16.4 installed.
And I'm using it as a samba file server, but it is consuming a lot of power.
It switches off its display after 5 minutes.
Samba is using wireless network not wired.
So what can I do to save power.
It's using around 17 to 19  watts.
It's a Lenovo laptop, Lenovo1000 G410.

Comment: It might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/203303/power-savings-and-performance-modes-on-ubuntu-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power Savings and Performance Modes on Ubuntu System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203303/power-savings-and-performance-modes-on-ubuntu-system)